# Infection risk for young puppies due to being flooded previously

Tags: dogs, vaccination, puppy

We got flooded around mid November. Water went up to the half of our 2nd flood so there was mud and sewage water everywhere. Majority of the cleaning on the house was finished around mid December but not yet perfectly clean (edges and probably some seepage into the walls/furniture). It's already January 10th (got the pup today and was born on early to mid November).

We got a new pomeranian puppy only 2 months old and I am wondering if there are viruses or bacteria that survived for a month or so due to the flood that can potentially kill it.

We don't often get puppies and it was the first time we had one in a decade or so. The owner advises us to keep the puppy in a cage until it is vaccinated for the 3rd time which is around 1 more month. The pup will receive its 2nd vaccination on January 12th. Since viruses and bacteria are invisible to the eye, I want to know if we should just cage it and prevent it from running around a room to prevent it from getting sick

Comment: I guess the answer depends on where you live and what microbes (bacteria, fungi, parasites) usually live in your environment. I doubt that viruses can survive this long when they dry out, but all the other microbes could in theory survive. If the "cage" for your puppy is big enough, like a big playpen, or you can keep it in an already cleaned room, I see no big problems. If you're thinking of a crate, that is definitely too small to keep  puppy in for several weeks.